# Store the float value in array, and analyzing last 20 values to check in C++

Tags: arrays, loops, c++11, arduino

I'm working with DS18B20 Temperature sensor with Arduino. I need to store the last 20 read values in array, and notify or interrupt to switch on the LED particular threshold. How to process the above scenario? You can add the rest of the codes with my initial code.

```
#include <OneWire.h> 
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
 
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 10 
 
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS); 
 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
/********************************************************************/ 
void setup(void) 
{ 
 // start serial port 
 Serial.begin(9600); 
 sensors.begin(); 
} 
void loop(void) 
{ 
  readTempSensor();
       delay(100); 
} 

float readTempSensor(){
 float Temp = 0;
 float TmpArray[20]; 
 
 sensors.requestTemperatures();
 Temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
 
 Serial.print("T: "); 
 Serial.println(Temp); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::array<float, 20>` and keep track of the index, modding it when necessary:

```cpp
//cstddef shouldn't be required due to the inclusion of <array>,
//but if it still throws an error, uncomment the following line
//#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

static constexpr std::size_t max_histogram_count = 20;
static std::array<float, max_histogram_count> histogram{};

void readTempSensor() {
    static std::size_t histogramIndex = 0;

    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    const auto curTemp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    histogram[histogramIndex++] = curTemp;

    for(const auto& h : histogram) {
        Serial.print("T: ");
        Serial.println(h);
    }

    histogramIndex %= max_histogram_count;
}

void analyzeTemperature() {
    //...Do things with histogram array
}
```

Comment: i have an error `'size_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`  . Can you check where these lines will come    `static constexpr std::size_t max_histogram_count = 20;
static std::array<float, max_histogram_count> histogram{};
`

Comment: @Dilux This was just an example usage; I've added the headers to make it complete.

Comment: @Dilux If this answer satisfied your question, please mark it as accepted.